# Authentication error with Rfacebook

Tags: r, ssl, ssl-certificate

I'm getting the following error authenticating in R with the Rfacebook package. I'm using a RHEL virtual machine...

> Authentication complete. Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)
>   :    SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details:
>   error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate
>   verify failed

Please let me know how I can fix this. I have all the needed certificates installed in firefox..

Thanks,
Sam.

Comment: Please provide [a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) that includes a minimal example of the code that produces this error.

Comment: The fact that the certificate is installed in Firefox doesn't mean it's installed for the R client that's trying to make this connection. You'll need to provide more details about how you're making the connection.